# How does one manage a mix of synchronous and asynchronous processes in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process, synchronization

**Desired Outcome:**

Define a mix of synchronous and asynchronous method relationships.

**Example**

Assume 4 methods, each containing a single process where:

1. Method.ProcessA1 must start and finish before Method.ProcessA2 is invoked (synchronous relationship).
2. Method.ProcessB1 must start and finish before Method.ProcessB2 is invoked (synchronous relationship).
3. Method.ProcessA and Method.ProcessB may start and finish irrespective of each other and in parallel (asynchronous relationship).

The flow chart shown in the following link more clearly illustrates the desired synchronicity. Processes flow chart is like the following:

[image]

There is an async method, perhaps its usage would be appropriate here.

*Note: I am new to SO and open to advice on writing higher quality questions.*

Comment: What do you want to do? This is rather abstract... does this boil down to "how do I run two async methods at the same time" or am I misreading it? (I'm not downvoter. In general though, it does seem like you could do more research before bringing this question here.)

Comment: I basically want to do 4 things where some must precede others while others can run in parallel.  More specifically, the things I want to do involve calling multiple instances of command line applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void ProcessA()
{
    ProcessA1();
    ProcessA2();
}

void ProcessB()
{
    ProcessB1();
    ProcessB2();
}

void LaunchProcesses()
{
    Task aTask = Task.Run((Action)ProcessA); //You could also call use Task.Run(() => ProcessA());
    Task bTask = Task.Run((Action)ProcessB);
    aTask.Wait();
    bTask.Wait();
}
```

Comment: Greg, this is very clear and simple.  Will give it a shot in my application but it demonstrates you understood the question.

Comment: It turns out this approach leads to a compile error.  'ProcessA' and 'ProcessB' are declared as methods.  However, Task.Run() is looking for an 'Action' as an argument.  The compiler error is 'CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action'.

Comment: An action is a method that doesn't return a value, but I see that there's an overload for Task.Run that takes a task, causing the parameter to be ambiguous. I've edited the answer to disambiguate the parameter. This runs in .Net 4.6

Comment: Here's an example from Microsoft.  Instead of calling Task.Run() on a method, it suggests making the action the argument itself.  It seems a bit messy if the action is extensive.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Anonymous  method declaration is always an option, but in your case it would disguise the intent, which is to call ProcessA. Clarity of Intention is a popular idea in programming, as it makes code more declarative, and easier to maintain.